# how to show name for city when i make map using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to know why i could not show the city name for my map.

In the last function, it can `console.log` the city name, but it didn't show at page.

Thanks very much for your answer.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>中国地图</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width  = 1000;
var height = 1000;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
//投影函数
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([107, 31])//设置中心位置
    .scale(2000)//设置放大比例
    .translate([width/2, height/2]);//设置平移
//地理生成器：根据地理数据生成SVG的path元素的路径值
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var color = d3.scale.category20();

d3.json("yunnan.json", function(error, root) {
    if (error)
        return console.error(error);
    // console.log(root.features);

    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data( root.features )
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("stroke","#000")
        .attr("stroke-width",1)
        .attr("fill","#b6c9f7")
        .attr("d", path )
        .on("mouseover",function(d,i){
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("fill","#778de6");
        })
        .on("mouseout",function(d,i){
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("fill","#b6c9f7");
        })
        .append("text")
        .text(function (d) {
            console.log(d.properties.name);
            return d.properties.name;
        });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text` is not an allowed child of `path`, and you don't position the text in the svg

Comment: could you give me some suggests to add city name for my map?thanks a lot

Comment: you are the first with this problem so a search on this would probably give you a lot of hits on how to fix this in D3

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please either post a solution or delete your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution for this question.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>云南地图</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.ourd3js.com/library/multext.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
var width  = 630;
var height = 630;
var svg = d3.select("body")//定位页面位置
    .append("svg")//添加画布
    .attr("width", width)//添加宽度
    .attr("height", height)//添加高度
    .append("g")//添加元素
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
//投影函数
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()//投影方式
    .center([102, 25])//设置中心位置，数据是指经纬度
    .scale(3800)//设置放大比例
    .translate([width/2, height/2]);//设置平移
//地理生成器：根据地理数据生成SVG的path元素的路径值
var path = d3.geo.path()//svg的预定义元素：rect矩形、circle圆形、eclipse椭圆、line线段、polyline折线、polygon多边形、path路径
    .projection(projection);//从球面投影到平面

// var color = d3.scale.category20();
// console.log(path);
d3.json("yunnan.json", function(error, root) {
    if (error)
        return console.error(error);
    // console.log(root.features);
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data( root.features )//引入数据
        .enter()
        .append("path")//添加路径
        .attr("stroke","#fff")//设置边线颜色
        .attr("stroke-width",1)//设置边线宽度
        .attr("fill","#b6c9f7")//设置填充颜色
        .attr("d", path )
        .on("mouseover",function(d,i){//设置鼠标悬浮样式
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("fill","#778de6");
        })
        .on("mouseout",function(d,i){//设置鼠标离开样式
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("fill","#b6c9f7");
        });
    var name=[];
    var local=[];
    for(var i=0;i<root.features.length;i++){
        name.push(root.features[i].properties.name);
        local.push(root.features[i].properties.cp);
    }
    for(var j=0;j<name.length;j++){
        var localPosition=projection(local[j]);
        appendMultiText(svg,name[j],localPosition[0]-30,localPosition[1]-10,70,14);

    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```